# datatable data not getting written to xlsx file

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatable

I used [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) to implement in my project and I was able to place the buttons on my page. The sample data that I have on my datatable which is displayed on the screen has an XML file in string format like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="" xmlns:urn1="test"> 
    <soapenv:Header>
```

Now, when I click on the Excel button it asks me to save the file, but when I open the file it gives me an error below.

> We have found a problem with some content in .xlsx. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can

When I open the file nothing gets written to it. I believe this could be because the data I have on the page.

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    'copyHtml5',
    'excelHtml5',
    'csvHtml5',
    'pdfHtml5'
],
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to write this as an answer but my reputation does not allow me to comment. I was facing the same issue. I was facing this issue because my code was not writing anything in the document. Please check your writing part.

Comment: Using the mentioned example, we generally don't have to do anything to write it in xlsx file. If we include all the dependencies mentioned, then it automatically gets written. I was able to use COPY, CSV option perfectly. But even when i click on PDF file, only half page data gets written in PDF file, whereas as mentioned nothing gets written in .xlsx file